# suppress specific \newcommand

Tags: macros

In my code, I use this command :

```
\newcommand{\boldstraightmath}[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
```

The problem is that Mathtype does not recognize specific (or customized) command such as `\boldstraightmath`.
For example, the following equation is not well translated by mathtype recognize only classic Latex functions.

```
\boldstraightmath{C}_i(\boldstraightmath{q})=\mathrm{exp}(\boldstraightmath{Y}_1q_1)\cdot \mathrm{exp}(\boldstraightmath{Y}_2q_2)\cdot ...\cdot \mathrm{exp}(\boldstraightmath{Y}_iq_i)\boldstraightmath{A}_i
```

Consequently, I need to transform the command `\boldstraightmath` and coming back to initial definitions with classic functions such as: `\bm{\mathrm{C}}`.
Is there a way to come back to my original code without `newcommand`?
I need a better thing than find/ replace \boldstraightmath by `\bm{\mathrm{A+}}`

Comment: if thee system you are using doesn't understand tex defintions you can not solve it from tex so you will need to just replace the command using your editor

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok but how can i do a smart find/ replace operation which works with a function ? in a editor like notepad++ for example

Comment: That is an editor specific question so not clearly related to tex or this site, but I'm sure notepad++ will have a regular expression replace

Comment: incidentally why are you using `\bm{\mathrm{C}}`  that is just a slow and complicated way get `\mathbf{C}`

Comment: There are some approaches described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67709/is-there-a-script-that-reads-a-tex-file-and-replaces-every-instance-of-a-newcom. But indeed `\mathbf{}` seems simpler.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604051/de-macro-has-no-effect/604086.